# Where is the target ISBN in feeds module?

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm using an ISBN module that create a simple textfield with "ISBN" as a type (this module makes validation of the books ISBN when inserted on the textfield when creating a book) It's a pretty cool module.

But now i want to populate my database with books from a CSV file, so in the header i've : "title, author,..,ISBN" i import this CSV file using feeds module, everything is imported except the ISBN. Even when i want to create a mapping for ISBN, i can't find field_data_field_isbn in the targets list. I know that the ISBN module makes validation (or not) for isbns only if you "write it" manually using the textfield. But is there any way to get ISBN from CSV with feeds (it's not important if it's validated or not) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The ISBN Field module doesn't support Feeds yet. Every module that provides a field should write their own mapper to support Feeds, as Feeds isn't able to dynamically know how to populate a field.

In the ISBN Field issue queue there is a patch available which might solve your problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/1930538